# Is the set $[-\infty, x)$ an open or closed set? Also a question about measurable functions.

Tags: real-analysis

As the title says.

I am asking this question because in Stein's Real Analysis, on page 29, it says that "if $f$ is measurable and finite-valued, and $\Phi$ is continuous, then $\Phi \circ f$ is measurable." It specifically mentioned "finite-valued". I was wondering why it needs to be finite valued.

The way the proof (slightly different from his version) goes is like this: We know that by definition, a function $f$ is measurable iff $f^{-1}(O)$ is measurable for any open set $O$. Then, given any open set $O$ and continuous function $\Phi$, we know that $\Phi^{-1} (O)$ is open. Hence, $(\Phi \circ f)^{-1} (O) = f^{-1} \circ \Phi^{-1} (O)$ is measurable. Hence, $\Phi \circ f$ is a measurable function.

It does not seem that we need to assume that $f$ is finite valued.

Comment: Can you extend a continuous function to $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$?

Comment: Henry is right. Then $\Phi\circ f$ is not defined.

Comment: @HenryW. It seems like you can: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354319/can-a-function-be-considered-continuous-if-it-reaches-infinity-at-one-point

Comment: For the extended real line it's an open set (which, in case you didn't know, doesn't prevent it from being a closed set in general topological spaces).